# Docker compose dind deploy to GitLab Registry

Tags: docker-compose, deployment, gitlab, registry, gitlab-ci

I am working on MS Blazor server two projects solution (Core 6) and GitLab.

docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  admin:

    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}admin

    build:

      context: .

      dockerfile: FrontEnd/Admin/Dockerfile

  enrollment:

    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}enrollment

    build:

      context: .

      dockerfile: FrontEnd/Enrollment/Dockerfile
```

GitLab pipeline file:

```
image: docker:stable

services:

  - docker:dind

before_script:

  - docker info

build:  

  only:

    - DockerComposeSupported

  before_script:

    - docker login registry.gitlab.com -u ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} -p ${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}

  script:

    - apk add --no-cache docker-compose

    - docker-compose build #Works fine

    - docker push ${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH} # Here is the error

  after_script:

    - docker logout ${CI_REGISTRY}

  stage: build
```

The problem is in line: - docker push ${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}, the error is
The push refers to repository [registry.gitlab.com/xxx/yyy/zzz]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: registry.gitlab.com/xxx/yyy/zzz

I originally grab the code from Gitlab, it was
docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/xxx/yyy/zzz .
But the docker build is looking for a docker file in the root directory and I do not have one, I have docker-compose only so I need to use the "docker-compose build" but this command does not have any directory parameter.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the DOCKER_REGISTRY variable set in the GitLab runner environment? You can check by placing a `printenv` statement within your script section.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks for pointing me to this! But now I have the error on the "docker push" command: requested access to the resource is denied. I already have all permission set up properly. If I use the "docker build" command on a single project solution the "docker push" command works fine. But if I use the "docker-compose build" then the next "docker push" returns the error: requested access to the resource is denied.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Richard and Danielnelz! I've found a solution for the "requested access to the resource is denied" error. I had "{CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}-admin" project reference but it should be {CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/admin. Now the docker push to the GitLab registry is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different variable defined by GitLab in CI: `CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE="registry.example.com/org/repo"`

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  admin:
    image: ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}-admin
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: FrontEnd/Admin/Dockerfile
  enrollment:
    image: ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}-enrollment
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: FrontEnd/Enrollment/Dockerfile
```

docker-compose has a nifty feature where you can set this variable in a `.env` file within the same directory as the docker-compose.yml file. You will only need this file for local development.

```
# .env
CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE="registry.example.com/org/repo"
```

- [GitLab Docs: Predefined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)
- [Docker Docs: The .env file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file)

Comment: Thanks, your idea is exactly what I was looking for! 
Now it builds fine but I have the error on the next step: 
a552ee10a343: Preparing 
c3fb4b036056: Preparing 
9c1b6dd6c1e6: Waiting denied: requested access to the resource is denied

Comment: Please update your post with your .gitlab-ci.yml changes